# Max(Sum of squares mod m)

Tags: python

```
n-> number of lists
m->modulo
Constraints
1<=n<=7
1<=m<=1000
1<=Magnitude of elements in list<=10*9
1<=Elements in each list<=7
```

This snippet of code is responsible for maximizing (x1^2 + x2^2 + ...) % m where x1, x2, ... are chosen from lists X1, X2, ...

```
n,m = map(int,input().split())
max_sum = 0
for _ in range(n):
    l = [(int(x)**2)%m for x in input().split()[1:]]
    #print(l)
    max_sum += max(l)
print(max_sum%m)
```

So for instance, if inputs are :

```
7 867
7 6429964 4173738 9941618 2744666 5392018 5813128 9452095
7 6517823 4135421 6418713 9924958 9370532 7940650 2027017
7 1506500 3460933 1550284 3679489 4538773 5216621 5645660
7 7443563 5181142 8804416 8726696 5358847 7155276 4433125
7 2230555 3920370 7851992 1176871 610460 309961 3921536
7 8518829 8639441 3373630 5036651 5291213 2308694 7477960
7 7178097 249343 9504976 8684596 6226627 1055259 4880436
```

The expected output is 866, but I am getting 327.

I know the solution to the problem but I would like to know the error in my code. The properties I have used are:

1. Sum of mod = Mod of sum
2. For a sum to be maximum its summand should of maximum

Comment: Both of your number claims are incorrect.  Please return to your educational materials on modulus and learn the mechanics and properties of the operator.  Your misunderstandings lead directly to code that doesn't particularly attempt to solve the given problem.

Comment: Are you asking if the *properties* you used are valid or are you asking if your code faithfully  implements those *properties*?

Comment: @Prune The first claim is mathematically true, but misleading in languages where the *remainder* operation is not a true *modulo*. (The difference is what happens for negative operands.) Python's `%` operator *does* behave like a modulo operation, for example `(-2) % 5 == 3`, so this is not the problem here - it also wouldn't be the problem in other languages because the numbers are squared first, so they're all positive anyway.

Comment: @kaya3: The first claim is false.  The sum of mods can easily exceed the modulus itself.  Take a trivial case: 4(mod 5) + 4(mod 5) => 8, but (4 + 4)(mod 5) => 3.

Comment: @Prune, in this context what "sum of mod = mod of sum" means is that repeatedly doing `total = (total + x) % m` will give the same result as `total = total + x` and then doing `total = total % m` at the end. It is a mathematical fact that these give the same result if `%` is the modulo operator, rather than the remainder operator which exists in some languages. It is clear from the OP's code that they did not forget to do the `% m` at the end, so you are misinterpreting the statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is logically wrong; ignore the squaring part, and consider the case where the two lists are `[1, 2]` and `[1, 2]`, and the modulus is 3. In this case the maximum sum modulo 3 is 1 + 1 = 2, choosing the *minimum* element of each list, not the maximum. Your algorithm would select 2 + 2 = 1 (mod 3), a smaller sum.

Your proposition that *"For a sum to be maximum its summand should of maximum"* is correct outside of modular arithmetic, but not correct in this context.